# How to count occurrence of elements in an array as new column in SQL table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table called `my.table` and a `split` function that is already defined and returns an array of strings.

```
SELECT split(lang) as langs
FROM my.table 

which returns:

+-----------------------------+
|           langs             |
+-----------------------------+
| [French, English, English]  |
+-----------------------------+
| [Dutch, French, English]    |
+-----------------------------+
| [English]                   |
+-----------------------------+
| [French, Dutch]             |
+-----------------------------+
```

Now I am trying to apply `unnest` to turn the above into a table with occurrence of each language, for example:

```
+--------------------------+
| English | French | Dutch | 
+--------------------------+
|    2    |    1   |   0   |    # corresponds to [French, English, English] (0 Dutch)
+--------------------------+
|    1    |    1   |   1   | 
+--------------------------+
|    1    |    0   |   0   | 
+--------------------------+
|    0    |    1   |   1   | 
+--------------------------+
```

I can count the total number of say 'English' in a naive way such as:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT split(lang) as langs
FROM my.table)
SELECT count(arr_item) as English
FROM x, UNNEST(arr) as arr_item where arr_item = 'English'
```

**Edited**:
Each row may contain repeated elements like `[English, English, French]`. See first table:row1.

So the output for that one is shown in the second table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Most likely number of languages in your data is not known in advance - so I recommend below approach which first collect all languages in data and puts it in alphabetical order and then for each row produces vector of 0s and 1s representing existence of respective language based on their position in that base languages list

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'French,English' langs UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dutch,French,English' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'English' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'French,Dutch' 
), base AS (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(lang ORDER BY lang) all_langs
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT lang
    FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
    UNNEST(SPLIT(langs)) lang
  )
)
SELECT langs, all_langs,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(IF(lang IS NULL, '0', '1') ORDER BY pos)
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(all_langs)) base_lang WITH OFFSET pos
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(langs)) lang
    ON base_lang = lang
  ) AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
CROSS JOIN base b
```

result is

```
Row langs                   all_langs               value    
1   French,English          Dutch,English,French    0,1,1    
2   Dutch,French,English    Dutch,English,French    1,1,1    
3   English                 Dutch,English,French    0,1,0    
4   French,Dutch            Dutch,English,French    1,0,1
```

Hope, this will give you good starting point for your specific use case

Note: BigQuery does not support native PIVOT'ing, so above approach is most likely the most optimal for you

> ... my rows are array of strings already ... I have [‘French’, ‘English’] instead of ‘French, English’ ... So does that still work?

Absolutelly - Yes! The only change you need to do is to replace `UNNEST(SPLIT(langs))` with `UNNEST(langs)` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['French','English'] langs UNION ALL
  SELECT ['Dutch','French','English'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['English'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['French','Dutch'] 
), base AS (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(lang ORDER BY lang) all_langs
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT lang
    FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
    UNNEST(langs) lang
  )
)
SELECT langs, all_langs,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(IF(lang IS NULL, '0', '1') ORDER BY pos)
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(all_langs)) base_lang WITH OFFSET pos
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(langs) lang
    ON base_lang = lang
  ) AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
CROSS JOIN base b
```

with result

[image]

> if a row is [French, English, English]. desired is 0,1,2

see example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['French','English','English'] langs UNION ALL
  SELECT ['Dutch','French','English'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['English','English'] UNION ALL
  SELECT ['French','Dutch'] 
), base AS (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(lang ORDER BY lang) all_langs
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT lang
    FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
    UNNEST(langs) lang
  )
)
SELECT langs, all_langs,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT CAST(SUM(IF(lang IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS STRING) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(all_langs)) base_lang WITH OFFSET pos
    LEFT JOIN UNNEST(langs) lang
    ON base_lang = lang
    GROUP BY base_lang
    ORDER BY MIN(pos)
  ), ',') AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
CROSS JOIN base b
```

with result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As my rows are array of strings already, I think I need to kinda modify your first part. For example, in line 3 of your code, I have `[‘French’, ‘English’]` instead of `‘French, English’`. So does that still work?

Comment: That should be simple adjustment in code. You should try by yourself. Meantime, when I will be back to PC I will update my answer

Comment: It returns 0,1,1,1 if a row is [French, English, English]. desired is 0,1,2